# Property or method not defined in entity

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have a `Usuario` entity defined as follow:

```
namespace Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * Usuario.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Repository\UsuarioRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 *
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Usuario implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @todo No recibir ofertas del usuario.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity\Empresa")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="no_ofertas",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="empresa_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     *
     * @Serializer\Expose
     * @Serializer\Type("ArrayCollection<Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity\Empresa>")
     * @Serializer\MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $noOfertas;

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->noOfertas = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Add noOfertas.
     * @param \Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity\Empresa $noOfertas
     * @return Usuario
     */
    public function addNoOfertas(Empresa $noOfertas)
    {
        $this->noOfertas[] = $noOfertas;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove noOfertas.
     * @param \Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity\Empresa $noOfertas
     */
    public function removeNoOfertas(Empresa $noOfertas)
    {
        $this->noOfertas->removeElement($noOfertas);
    }

    /**
     * Get noOfertas.
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getNoOfertas()
    {
        return $this->noOfertas;
    }
}
```

Any time I try to update a `Usuario` I got this error:

> Neither the property "noOfertas" nor one of the methods
>   "addNoOferta()"/"removeNoOferta()", "setNoOfertas()", "noOfertas()",
>   "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class
>   "Checkengine\DashboardBundle\Entity\Usuario".

This is the `updateAction()` method:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('DashboardBundle:Usuario')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Usuario entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

    $current_pass = $entity->getPassword();
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        if (null == $entity->getPassword()) {
            $entity->setPassword($current_pass);
        } else {
            $this->setSecurePassword($entity);
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('usuarios_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'form'        => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

What could be wrong there? What I'm missing? I have clear the cache several times also restart the webserver (just in case) and nothing issue still and it's driving me crazy, any advice? clue?

Comment: try to do a `var_dump(get_class($objectYouAreTesting));`

Comment: @alfallouji where? In my controller? And how this will help me?

Comment: In the place, where it is calling the method and generating the error. It will help you make sure that you are actually have an instance of the class Usuario. If you don't, then at least you know what is wrong.

Comment: addNoOferta() vs addNoOfertas() Look closely.  Can you spot the difference?

Comment: @Cerad are you asking to me?

Comment: Yes, I was asking you.  The error message complains about not being able to find addNoOferta().  You do have a method called addNoOfertas().  The extra 's' is a problem.

Comment: @Cerad yeah already notice that from **gp_sflover** answer but can you take a look to the comment I leave on his answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As showed in the error message you need to add/remove a `$noOferta` object and not the entire collection `$noOfertas`.

You need to rewrite the methods like this:

```
public function addNoOferta(Empresa $noOferta)
{
    $this->noOfertas[] = $noOferta;

    return $this;
}

public function removeNoOferta(Empresa $noOferta)
{
    $this->noOfertas->removeElement($noOferta);
}
```

Comment: That helps to clear the method names but the real problem comes from the `UsuarioType` class since someone was added this line `->add('noOfertas', 'hidden')` which causes the code to fails, my question is, why? I just commented that line and all works fine but don't know if this is the way to go, a clue? a advise?